# how to add column to each result of select statement with specific string?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In SQL (MS Access),
how do I create a query with select statement, that adds a new column with a specific string to each resulting row?

My statement

```
Select x,y,z
from [List]
where ((([List].a like "something"));
```

I get a few rows as result and would like to add a column that does not exist in [List] which is populated with one string for each result.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a column with a fixed value to the resultset, just do:

```
Select x, y, z, "some constant value" as a
from [List]
where a = "something";
```

Notes:

- MS Access really loves parentheses, but I don't think that your query needs some for this `where` clause with a single condition
- `a like "something"` is strictly equivalent to `a = "something"`